# cakephp display array name in form input options instead of variable

Tags: arrays, forms, cakephp, input

If i have an array such as

```
[Yellow] => 1 [Red] => 2 [Blue] => 3
```

and then want to use these in a form INPUT with $options to make a dropdown selection, is it possible to use the color names Yellow/Red/Blue instead of the values 1/2/3?

currently the dropdown has 1, 2, 3 as the options instead of the names. The array is used elsewhere and is in the format for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `array_flip` method to swap the keys and values around

```
$array = array('Yellow' => 1, 'Red' => 2, 'Blue' => 3);

$flippedArray = array_flip($array);

// => [1] => 'Yellow', [2] => 'Red', [3] => 'Blue'
```

Then use the flippedArray as the options in your select element with the form helper

```
echo $this->Form->select('colours', $flippedArray);
```

Or you could combine the colours into a new array for the select element

```
$combinedArray = array_combine(array_keys($array), array_keys($array));

//=> [Yellow] => 'Yellow', [Red] => 'Red', [Blue] => 'Blue'

echo $this->Form->select('colours', $combinedArray);
```

In this way you could then use the value passed back from your form as the key of your orignal array if you needed to

Comment: that is awesome, thanks for the options, that second one will work a treat!.